# Is It Possible To Have Bind Answer Authoritatively For Local Domains?

Tags: dns, bind, nameserver

Just as the title says: is it possible to have *Bind* (*named* service) on a Linux machine (Fedora 27, Server Edition) answer authoritatively for local domains or, at the very least, answer in such a way that something enquiring about them will accept the server's answer over any other?

I know that is is supposed to be possible (in theory, at least), but I cannot get it working, even though both the *named* and *rndc* services are and even though my files pass checks on both *named-checkconf* and *named-checkzone*.

I need to be able to receive an answer from the Bind server for my local domain (enquiries originating from a Windows 7 PC) that points to my local domain (as opposed to an authoritative or non-authoritative answer elsewhere on the internet), similar to this post: [BIND9 cannot resolve local domain](https://superuser.com/questions/1169801/bind9-cannot-resolve-local-domain). I would also like to make it possible to add in other (internet) domain names at a later date (so a fake root would probably not work as a solution) but, as it stands, the *nslookup* answer is:

** server can't find vpntest.it: NXDOMAIN **

I have also reinstalled the distro (bare minimum install), modified the files according to the Fedora Administrator's Guide, and have checked (plus carefully extrapolated from) this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/838380/dns-use-public-domain-name-for-internal-use ...and **still** receive the above error. Grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr!

My files are currently as follows:

**/etc/nsswitch.conf** value:

```
files dns myhostname
```

**/etc/resolv.conf:**

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 64.83.128.50
nameserver 64.20.192.50
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
# NOTE: the libc resolver may not support more than 3 nameservers.
# The nameservers listed below may not be recognized.
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844
```

**/etc/hosts:**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

**etc/named.conf** (RNDC Key deleted from this post):

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { 10.200.0.1; }; // 127.0.0.1 //
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";

    recursion no;
    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;
    allow-query { localhost; };
    version "Damned If I Know";
    allow-recursion { 10.200.0.1/24; };

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";

    include "/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
# include "/etc/named.root.key";

key "rndc-key" {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret "";
};

controls {
    inet 127.0.0.1 port 953
        allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};

zone "vpntest.it" IN {
    type master;
    file "vpntest.it.zone";
};

zone "0.200.10.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type master;
    file "10.200.0.zone";
    allow-update { none; };
};
```

**/var/named/vpntest.it.zone:**

```
$ORIGIN vpntest.it.
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA    ns1.vpntest.it.    hostmaster.vpntest.it. (
                100 ; serial
                21600   ; refresh after 6 hours
                3600    ; retry after 1 hour
                604800  ; expire after 1 week
                86400 ) ; minimum TTL of 1 day
;
                IN  NS  ns1.vpntest.it.
;
ns1             IN  A   10.200.0.1
;
www             IN  A   10.200.0.6
```

**/var/named/10.200.0.zone:**

```
$ORIGIN 0.200.10.in-addr.arpa.
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA    ns1.vpntest.it.    hostmaster.vpntest.it. (
                100 ; serial
                21600   ; refresh after 6 hours
                3600    ; retry after 1 hour
                604800  ; expire after 1 week
                86400 ) ; minimum TTL of 1 day
;
@               IN  NS  ns1.vpntest.it.
;
1               IN  PTR ns1.vpntest.it.
6               IN  PTR www
```

Comment: What is the IP address of your Nameserver? If it's not 10.200.0.1 that's your problem.  Also, you need to allow recursion for it to handle other domains.

Comment: is `nslookup vpntest.it` different from `nslookup vpntest.it 127.0.0.1` or such?

Comment: @davidgo: I will check now and see if that fixes the problem, - thanks.

Comment: @davidgo: sorry, - fix not successful ( ** server can't find vpntest.it: NXDOMAIN ** ). - I updated my vpntest.it.zone file NS A record and added an AAAA for FE80::1, so the nameserver IPs match those given in resolv.conf (where I also amended FE80::/64 to FE80::1). Recursion has also now been enabled in named.conf.

Comment: Changed file format to match naming conventions, so vpntest.it.zone changed to named.vpntest.it; likewise with the PTR file. Also removed recursion no; (to avoid a potential conflict with the allow-recursion directive), and used var/named/named.empty to create a stripped, conventionally-correct, named.vpntest.it. Result: still NXDOMAIN.

Comment: Checked var/named/data/named.run for errors (2 found: error writing NTA file for view '_default': permission denied ...and... error writing NTA file for view '_bind': permission denied). I am not sure whether these are important or not, or where to fix them, as I can find nothing of any use on the errors.

Comment: DNSSEC enforcement on the router was causing some issues, but that has been changed and is no longer affecting the DNS checks. Unfortunately it has not resolved the NXDOMAIN problem, either (ie: BIND _still_ will not accept that vpntest.it is a local domain.

Comment: Updated ethernet adapter file, changing the laptop address to a (local) static address to rule out any issues with DHCP assigning an unexpected, or ambiguous, IP address and matching the address to that already in the configuration files. Have _still_ got NXDOMAIN...

Comment: Ruled out satanforce, sorry _setenforce_, _firewalld_, router firewall, and anti-spoof.

Comment: Updated the root hints data file, overwriting the contents of named.ca with those of: ftp://ftp.rs.internic.net/domain/db.cache. _rndc reload_ threw no errors, _systemctl status named.service_ shows no errors, NXDOMAIN remains... (still no resolution to the internal (local) domain of vpntest.it).

Comment: Added both forwarders and forward first directive for the gateway (ns1) address. In theory this should try querying the ISP nameservers first and then fall-back to an internal query. In practise vpntest.it remains stuck at NXDOMAIN.

Comment: Checked out guides on using fake root and can confirm that it is essentially what I now have anyway, seeing as using a fake root is primarily about locking the nameserver down to serving local domain names which may or may not mirror other domains already existing on the internet.

Comment: Gone over the logs, ping checks, nmap, again. - BIND is definitely talking to our ISP and there is definitely two-way communication. I have no further ideas on this and can only conclude that the latest version of BIND is in some way broken. According to every guide I have read (there must be at least a thousand in English alone), my configuration should definitely be resolving, even as non-authoritative, my local domain(s) and it most definitely is not, even with everything stripped, reset, cleaned, convention matched, etc..

Comment: @thrig: my apologies, - I failed to see what you were doing with that check when I first looked at it but, yes, nslookup vpntest.it 127.0.0.1 does return: Name: vpntest.it Address: 127.0.0.1

Comment: You are not specifying exactly how you check. But `nslookup` (tip1: use `dig` instead but the following applies to) without the nameserver you want to query will do the normal resolution. So is your domain properly delegated? Test with online tools such as ZoneMaster or DNSViz. Try `dig` with `@` + your nameserver IP and compare results when you do not specify. Now, it is not a good idea to have a bind both as recursive and authoritative. AS per my other comment, `dnsmasq` may be a better fit for your situation.

Comment: Thanks, - I did try dnsmasq, but got absolutely nowhere with it. For starters, I could not find adequate information on how to use it, whether to use it in conjunction with BIND, etc. and it just appeared to be a clone of BIND, so I am now using a proper domain instead, and just BIND ...but that has given me the headache of only being accessible to Googlebot and my local network.

Answer (score 0):

---

*I know this question is a bit old (and it seems like you have some semi-working configuration), so please forgive me if I state anything you are already aware of or that not longer applies to your issue.*

---

I can't speak directly to any other problems, but you (apparently) don't have an entry for *vpntest.it* in your zone file:

```
$ORIGIN vpntest.it.
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA    ns1.vpntest.it.    hostmaster.vpntest.it. (
                100 ; serial
                21600   ; refresh after 6 hours
                3600    ; retry after 1 hour
                604800  ; expire after 1 week
                86400 ) ; minimum TTL of 1 day
;
                IN  NS  ns1.vpntest.it.
;
ns1             IN  A   10.200.0.1
;
vpntest.it.     IN  A   10.200.0.6  ; http://vpntest.it - no subdomain
www             IN  A   10.200.0.6  ; http://www.vpntest.it - subdomain
```

Note that the serial should always be incremented when making changes to your zones.

**Other Notes**

- `.it` is a real TLD along with `.dev`. This can cause resolution issues (as can any real, public TLD). You may want to check this list of [International Top Level Domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) and pick a fake TLD that isn't on that list (e.g. `.nx` perhaps?). There are some [officially reserved non-public TLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Special-Use_Domains) (well, semi-excluding `.onion`) but `.invalid` is the one you would choose to be absolutely safe (avoid `.local` since this is used in conjunction with [zeroconf networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)).
- As you note in your comments, `recursion no;` should be removed (since you are already limiting recursion with `allow-recursion { 10.200.0.1/24; };`).
- Any computer that you wish `vpntest.it` to work with needs to have its DNS traffic pass through your BIND server.
- *hosts* can potentially override BIND. While `nsswitch.conf` wouldn't seem to be an issue (considering the order), this is probably still worthwhile to note for general troubleshooting (i.e. you shouldn't need `vpntest.it 127.0.0.1` when using BIND).
- While it doesn't apply to your issue, make sure to use e.g. `vpntest.it/` (note the trailing slash) to access custom domains in current versions of Chrome, Firefox and Opera (or other Chromium-derived browsers). Leaving it off can cause resolution issues as well (assuming DNS is working properly otherwise).